# How can one find a Gemarah Havruta in NYC?

Tags: torah-study, talmud-gemara, chutz-laaretz, adult-learning

For someone that has some basic gemarah skills with experience in learning the gemarah together with Rashi and Tosefot, what's a good resource for finding a daily havruta to study with in Brooklyn, NY.

Comment: go to a local shul or your own shul you attend and befriend people...be active

Comment: Go to a shul and ask the rabbi to find you someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What has worked for me is the following.

1 - Hanging up signs in a few local Shuls saying that I am looking for a Chavrusa during the following hours to learn the following type of learning, with my phone number.

2 - Asking neighbors if they are looking to learn with someone.

3 - Asking my Rabbi if he can suggest anyone.

Hatzlacha upon your quest.

Answer (score 1):

This site can help chavrusa match

http://www.chavrusamatch.com/

Comment: It doesn't seem to be very active. I guess I'll need to consult with a rabbi.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://yagdiltorah.org/chavrusa. I don't know how active it is, but you can take a look there.